# Pointer to Array Pointer (char** arrptr = &arr)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

i try to initialize a pointer pointing to a pointer pointing to a char (char**):

`char arr[8]; char ** arrptr = &arr;`

and i get the warning:
"initialization from incompatible pointer type"

Whats wrong with that?

Comment: The type of `&arr` is `char (*)[8]`. With that said, what are you really trying to do? What is the pointer supposed to be used for? What is the actual problem you try to solve with this pointer?

Comment: Aye, why do you want a `char **` (a pointer to a pointer, this second pointer being a pointer to a `char`)

Comment: Arrays do not decay to pointer when address-of operator (`&`) is applied. Thus `&` applied to `char[8]` object returns `char(*)[8]`

Comment: The question you should be asking here is rather "why am I trying to assign a `char**` from a `char` array"? Because that doesn't make sense. You may use a `char**` to point at the first `char*` in an array of `char*`, each pointing at an array. But this is not it.

Comment: to add further clarity: i have a function that takes a pointer to an array pointer. This function prints to this array while incrementing the pointer. void sbprintf(char **buf, size_t *bufsize, const char * fmt, ...) (if buf is incremented, bufsize is decremented)

Comment: That feel like you should use a pointer, and then pass a pointer to the pointer variable, using the pointer-to operator `&`. Like emulating pass by reference in C. So e.g. `char *arr; size_t bufsize; sbprintf(&arr, &buffsize, ...);` What does the *documentation* for the function say? Who gave you that function? Who told you to use it? Ask that person to also help you to use it.

Comment: And please **[edit]** your question to include such important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&arr` returns a `char (*)[8]`, a pointer to an array of eight `char`.

```c
char (*arrptr)[8] = &arr;
```

---

`&( arr[0] )` returns a `char *`, a pointer to a character.

That character happens to be the first of eight, but that info isn't communicated by the type.

```c
char *arrptr = &( arr[0] );
```

Treating an array as a pointer cause the array to decay into a point to its first element. So this can be simplified to

```c
char *arrptr = arr;
```

---

A `char**` is a pointer to a pointer, the addressed pointer being a pointer to a `char`. This can be achieved as follows:

```c
char *p1 = arr;
char **p2 = &p1;
```

---

It's unclear what you need, but it's probably the middle one.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not decay to pointers when address-of operator (`&`) is applied.  Thus `&` applied to `char[8]` object returns a pointer to 8-element array of `char`: `char(*)[8]`.

To transform this object to `char**` you need a `char*` object which address can be taken. It can be achieved using a helper variable:

```
char arr[8];
char *tmp = arr;
char **arrptr = &tmp;
```

Or with a compound literal introduced in C99 revision of C language.

```
char arr[8];

char **arrptr = &(char*){ arr };
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have this function:

```c
void sbprintf(char **buf, size_t *bufsize, const char * fmt, ...)
```

We can't know for sure without documentation for this function, but the only interpretation where using `char **buf, size_t *bufsize` instead of `char *buf, size_t bufsize` makes sense is that `sbprintf` allocates the buffer and returns it and its size via parameters (much like GNU's [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)).

Here's how it would be used:

```c
char *buf = NULL;
size_t bufsize = 0;

sbprintf( &buf, &bufsize, "...", ... );

free( buf );
```

If it's like `getline`, it can accept a buffer allocated using `malloc` it can reallocate if necessary. This allows you to call `sbprintf` repeatedly with the same buffer.

```c
char *buf = NULL;
size_t bufsize = 0;

while ( ... ) {
   ...
   sbprintf( &buf, &bufsize, "...", ... );
   ...
}

free( buf );
```

Comment: sbprintf is a non standard function without documentation. It is used to print piecewise into a buffer, taking into account its limits. The buffer has to be allocated beforehand. e.g. `size_t bufsize=42; char buf[42]; char *hptr=buf; char** bufptr=&hptr; sbprintf(buf, &bufsize, "Hello "); sbprintf(buf, &bufsize, "World\n");`...

Comment: Re "*The buffer has to be allocated beforehand.*", How do you know? You just said you had no docs. And if that's true, its interface makes no sense. Why pass a pointer to two variables if you're not going to change them? But fine, I'll undelete my earlier answer which shows how to do what you did in the comment.

Comment: The pointer `bufptr` is incremented and `bufsize` is decremented. And i was just wondering why i cant write `&buf` e.g. `sbprint(&buf, &bufsize, "");`.

Comment: Really? Then how does `sbprintf` signal an error (e.g. insufficient space)??? You said the return type was `void`.  This function has a major problem.

Comment: You need to produce the address of the pointer to increment. But `&buf` doesn't produce the address of a pointer; it produces the address of an array. You can't increment an array, so even conceptually, it makes no sense.